# iOS - Problem loading a new view in a landscape orientation?

Tags: iphone, ios, view, size, orientation

I have two views in my App and i am having problem loading my second view when i rotate my emulator.

My first view redirects my app to second view on a button event.

When i try to rotate each view independently, it works perfect. But if i load my first view and rotate the emulator then try to load another view i am getting this :-

[image]

second view loaded as portrait where my emulator's orientation is landscape.

But if i load my second view before rotating the emulator and then rotate it, it gets loaded perfect.

Do i need to resize my view or need to call any function to make it load properly?

i am a newbie in iOS world so any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you add new view?

Comment: `- (IBAction)changeView:(id)sender 
{
    self.redClass = [[RedClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"RedClass" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:redClass.view];        
}` this is the way i am adding a new view.

Comment: As Nekto says below, merely adding more and more subviews generally isn't the correct way to write iOS apps. Instead, replace the view entirely using pushViewModally, a navigation controller, tab controller, or a custom root-view management class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that in your second view you use this method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

Comment: yeah i used this method that is why i said that when i redirect my app to second view and then rotate it, it works perfect but if i rotate first and then redirect my app to second view, it messed up.

Comment: Do you want it to rotate to portrait or do you want it always landscape? If you want it to rotate to fit then chances are the objects in your XIB file are setup wrong. Make sure everything is aligned the same and stretched horizontal for example (check out Inspector when editing the file).

Answer (score 0):

Add new view to `UINavigationController` using following code:

```
- (IBAction)changeView:(id)sender
{
    RedClass *redClass = [[RedClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"RedClass" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:redClass animated:YES];
    [redClass release];
}
```

If you cal that method then your view will autoresize.

When you just adding to subview using method `self.view addSubview:redClass.view];` it will `autoresize` if only current view will be changed after adding.